# How to check for a Guid.Empty Id of a client side dropdown

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following `ViewResult()` which populates a Model (holding two dropdowns) which in turn is sent to the strongly typed View().
Notice how I add a new “*---VIEW ALL---*“ value in both dropdowns with the **Id** being a `Guid.Empty.`

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult ManageUsers()
{
    var applicationList = _facade.Value.GetApplications().OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList();
    applicationList.Add(new Application() { Id = Guid.Empty, Name = "---VIEW ALL---" });

    var roleList = _facade.Value.GetRoles(applicationList.First().Id).OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList();
    roleList.Add(new Role() { Id = Guid.Empty, Name = "---VIEW ALL---" });

    var model = new ManageUsersModel();
    model.ApplicationList = new SelectList(applicationList, "Id", "Name", applicationList.First().Id);
    model.RoleList = new SelectList(roleList, "Id", "Name");

    return View(model);
}
```

Once inside the View() I create a `jquery .change()` event for the first dropdown and I wish to detect the selected value.

Based on the selected value, I need to take different actions. For example if the `Guid.Empty` value is selected then do this…if not, then to that…

So far the code I have in the .change() event looks like this:

```
$('#ApplicationId').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000") {
        alert("aaa");
    }
    else {
        alert("xxx");
    }
});
```

The code works but I find it **ugly** to check for the `Guid.Empty` the way I’m doing it.

Does anyone have a different/better approach to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Sincerely
Vlince

PS: Since this will be a Multilanguage application, I can’t use the `selected text` of the dropdown for the if(…) compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming Model.ApplicationList and Model.RoleList are a type of List such as  `List<SelectListItem>` and not an IEnumerable.  If so, why not append your empty, "---View All---" when you create the SelectList and use an empty string for the value.

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult ManageUsers()
{
    var applicationList = _facade.Value.GetApplications().OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList();
    var roleList = _facade.Value.GetRoles(applicationList.First().Id).OrderBy(a => a.Name).ToList();

    var model = new ManageUsersModel();
    model.ApplicationList = new SelectList(applicationList, "Id", "Name", applicationList.First().Id);
    model.RoleList = new SelectList(roleList, "Id", "Name");

    var defaultChoice = new SelectListItem("", "---VIEW ALL---")
    model.ApplicationList.InsertAt(0, defaultChoice);
    model.RoleList.InsertAt(0, defaultChoice);
    return View(model);
}
```

And your Javascript

```
$('#ApplicationId').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() === "") {
        alert("aaa");
    }
    else {
        alert("xxx");
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Model.ApplicationList and Model.RoleList are not typed as List<> nor IEnumerable. They are typed as a SelectList. Perhaps I need to change the types of both properties in order to achieve what you’ve shown. I will go and make the change. I like your answer, simple and clever! Thank you.